# How to integrate an image proxy server with a caching proxy?

Tags: image, caching, proxy, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

I have an imgproxy server, as shown below. It's able to transform an image (resize, crop) using URL parameters.
[image]

Now I would like to add a caching proxy. So an image only would be processed (resized, cropped) if that doesn't exist in the cache.

I've read that AWS Cloudfront or Cloudflare or maybe Google Cloud CDN could be the caching proxy, what would be great. But unfortunately I didn't find any example of how to do that. I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

On **Cloudflare**, you can leverage the following services for your use case:

- [Cloudflare Images](https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/cloudflare-images): for CDN, storage and resizing services
- [Cloudflare Image Resizing](https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/image-resizing), combined with the Cloudflare CDN via reverse proxy to allow on the fly resizing and optimization of the images (differences with Images [listed here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/faq#what-is-the-difference-between-cloudflare-images-and-image-resizing-products))
- You can also store and resize images on your site, using the Cloudflare CDN (DNS base reverse proxy) and put it in front of your image resizing and storage  stack. This is [explained here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/) in detail.

You can find here the steps to [create a Cloudflare account](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201720164-Creating-a-Cloudflare-account-and-adding-a-website) and add your domain to it.

Comment: Hi, Paolo. I don't want to use Cloudflare to resize or optimize the images. Imgproxy is already doing that. I just want to know how Cloudflare coud be used with Imgproxy to cache the images.

Comment: Point 3 of the above list would cover that option, in other words you would onboard your domain on Cloudflare, set up proxied DNS records and then configuring the cache as mentioned in the documentation I linked.

Comment: This is what the doc says: "Cloudflare makes customer websites faster by storing a copy of the website’s content on the servers of our globally distributed data centers". I don't have a website, but an image proxy server with my domain. Do you think it would work, Paolo?

Comment: If the images are available over http(s) then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Paolo just I also i had same doubt about how to cache, but in my case i want to use a self server,

I created a project they caches the images based on params and url requested these is generated an hash MD5, when the image with same params is requested the proxy search the md5 if is cached otherwise they regenerate a new one image resized

You can consider that for use to S3 / cloudflare any else

You can take a look of the project:

https://github.com/sefirosweb/Imgproxy-With-Cache